# How to integrate PLAID API with MS Power Apps Custom Connector?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, plaid

I'm in process of integrating Plaid API in MS Power Apps. I'm able to create custom connector and it's working fine.

Now when I'm hitting API to get a public token from Power Apps, it is giving me an error that secret is missing but the same request I'm passing using postman, I'm able to get public token.

Same behaviour I'm getting for other collections too.

Looking for inputs.

Comment: Can you provide the exact call and response (with the secret redacted out, of course)? What environment are you using (Sandbox, Production, Development)?

Comment: Sounds like you are making two calls with a Custom Connector; 1 to the Plaid token server to get an auth token for the request, 1 to the actual API with an authenticated request. You need to determine what the required parameters are for the token server. My guess is that it requires a Client_ID and Client_Secret of some sort. You probably have these set in Postman, but not in PowerApps (just a guess).